# Whats the difference between an Enterprise Application Project and an EJB Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I've seen that the Eclipse Java EE edition has both of these. What's the difference? Also is the Dynamic Web Project for creating REST services or the "Web Service" project?

Comment: An enterprise application can contain any combination of EJBs, a web application or a web service. An EJB project is just that: a jar with EJBs in it (and associated artefacts). You should try the options and see the results (or read the eclipse help file)

Comment: Basically EJB project creates a .jar with EJBs and Enterprise Application creates a EAR containing (those) JARs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Enterprise Application Project**

An enterprise application project ties together the resources that are required to deploy a J2EE enterprise application.
References [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcjearproj.html)

**EJB Project**
This provides a specialized environment that you can use to develop and test enterprise beans that conform to the distributed component architecture defined in the Sun Microsystems Enterprise JavaBeans™ (EJB) version specification. 

Reference [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcjearproj.html)